# Splitting string by space and number Ruby

Tags: ruby, split

how do I split string by space and following specific number? My string looks like

```
PID55688.00976 1
PID66854.76557 2
PID88774.23455 3
PID66843.99754 1
PID66800.00764 3
```

I want to split string by space and number 3

Code
`str.split(/\s3/)` does not split anything.

Comment: could you put how do you want the result?

Comment: I think it works https://ideone.com/S0K3Zd

Comment: You mention that your code "does not split anything". Well it does split the string, maybe not producing the output you want. Maybe you haven't assigned the string to the `str` variable correctly? See the HEREDOCS (<<) syntax in other answers.

Comment: Whenever you give an example in a question please show the desired result (as  Ruby object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces the expected output that OP has describe in the comments on @spickermann's answer:

```rb
string = <<-STRING
PID55688.00976 1
PID66854.76557 2
PID88774.23455 3
PID66843.99754 1
PID66800.00764 3
STRING

string.split(/ 3\n/).map{|substring| (substring+" 3").split(/\n/)}
```

but there's some typos in OP's expected answer, as there's no commas or quotes in the arrays. So I might have misinterpreted.

Comment: ...or `string.split(/(?<= 3)\n/).map{|substring| substring.split(/\n/)}`, `(?<= 3)` being a positive lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
string = <<-STRING
PID55688.00976 1
PID66854.76557 2
PID88774.23455 3
PID66843.99754 1
PID66800.00764 3
STRING

string.scan(/(\w+\.\w+ \w+)\n/).flatten
#=> [["PID55688.00976 1"], ["PID66854.76557 2"], ["PID88774.23455 3"], ["PID66843.99754 1"], ["PID66800.00764 3"]]
```

Comment: But I want to get something like this [[PID55688.00976 1
PID66854.76557 2
PID88774.23455 3], [PID66843.99754 1
PID66800.00764 3]]

Comment: mila, that's not a valid Ruby object. I expect you want `[["PID55688.00976 1",  "PID66854.76557 2", "PID88774.23455 3"], ["PID66843.99754 1", "PID66800.00764 3"]]` or `[["PID55688.00976 1 PID66854.76557 2 PID88774.23455 3"], ["PID66843.99754 1 PID66800.00764 3"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
[["PID55688.00976 1", "PID66854.76557 2", "PID88774.23455 3"],
 ["PID66843.99754 1", "PID66800.00764 3"]]
```

is the desired return value, one could write:

```
string.split(/\r?\n/).slice_after { |s| s.end_with?(' 3') }.to_a
```

See [Enumerable#slice_after](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after) and String#end_with?.